# 'if' and 'if not' in python, looping to search for a particular substring in a text file. what's the difference between the two? when to use which?

Tags: python, if-statement

Total noob here.

Language: Python3

I am doing a beginners course on Coursera, [Python for Everybody(specialization)](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/python?)
And also following the free textbook provided by course instructor Dr. Charles Severance. [Link to the textbook.](https://www.py4e.com/html3/)

I am trying to use a `for` loop in `Python` to search through a text file. I want to search for a substring through the whole text file. I am trying to do in two different ways.
[Link to the text file I am using.](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)

Sample one:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')

for lines in fhand :
    if lines.startswith('From:') :
        print(lines)
```

Sample two:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')

for lines in fhand :
    if not lines.startswith('From:') :
        continue
    print(lines)
```

The output is the same for both pieces of code:

```
From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za

From: louis@media.berkeley.edu

From: zqian@umich.edu

From: rjlowe@iupui.edu

From: zqian@umich.edu

From: rjlowe@iupui.edu

From: cwen@iupui.edu

From: cwen@iupui.edu

From: gsilver@umich.edu

From: gsilver@umich.edu

From: zqian@umich.edu

From: gsilver@umich.edu

From: wagnermr@iupui.edu

From: zqian@umich.edu

From: antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk

From: gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com

From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za

From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za

From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za

From: david.horwitz@uct.ac.za

From: stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za

From: louis@media.berkeley.edu

From: louis@media.berkeley.edu

From: ray@media.berkeley.edu

From: cwen@iupui.edu

From: cwen@iupui.edu

From: cwen@iupui.edu
```

Now what I don't understand is what's the difference in using `if` and `if not` in the above-mentioned code.

What goes on under-the-hood when I use them.

How are they different?

When to use which?

PS: if I have made some mistakes in posting this question then please let me know, I would be happy to comply.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read all this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Its very clear. The first condition says if your line starts from "From :" only then it will be printed. The second condition says if the line does not start with "From :" then continue the loop by and bring the next loop element and if the line had started from "From :" it would have been printed

Comment: Result-wise it makes no difference (True == not False). Performance-wise, your 2nd sample has to be a bit slower since more operations are involved. In a case like this however, I would opt for readability which depending on the case might benefit from either of the two samples, you have to be the judge of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines.startswith('From:')` and `not lines.startswith('From:')` do the "opposite".

If a line starts with `'From:'`, the first expression will be `True`.
If a line starts with `'From:'`, the second expression will be `False`.

However, in your specific case, the two code snippets are written in a way such that they behave the same.

The first snippet is easy to understand: If a line starts with `'From:'`, it is printed.

The second snippet achieves the same thing, but in a more convoluted way:

1. If a line does **NOT** start with `'From:'`, skip all other code in the `for` loop and start with the next iteration (this is what `continue` does).
2. Otherwise, print the line. (This instruction is only reached if `continue` does **NOT** execute.)

Comment: Thank you very much for providing such a clear explanation. One more thing I would like to ask, which sample code, if or if not would be more performance efficient if we were using a huge text file?

Answer (score 1):

`not` simply reverses the truth of an evaluation. If it was true it instead evaluates to false and vice versa. The outputs are the same because `continue` under the if statement is making the `not` a double negative. You essentially say don't not print.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the first code and as you rightly showed there isn't any difference in their output.

In the second sample if the 'From:' isn't present in the line, it 'continues'. Meaning it forgets about the print statement and just iterates to the next line. The reason I would use the first one is that it looks a lot less complex.

For someone reading your program, it'll be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

if Condition:
Evaluates to True and executes all the code in it, if the condition is true. for example if True: will evaluate to true.

if not Condition:
Used when you want to execute some piece of code for a false condition so instead of doing if this else that, you do it in one go,
so if not False: will evaluate to true and execute code in its block and if not True: does not execute any code in its block.

In your case your indentation is messed up, that's why your output is the same in both cases.

```
for lines in fhand :
    if not lines.startswith('From:') :
        print(lines)
```

Try this, it will not  print anything, since all your lines start wiht FROM:

```
for lines in fhand :
    if lines.startswith('From:') :
        print("case1")
        print(lines)
    if not lines.startswith("FROM:"):
        print("case2")
        print(lines)
```

Try this, all your output will be always form case 1.